# Riemann zeta sums and harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, riemann-zeta

Given the nth *harmonic number* of order *s*,

$$H_n(s) =\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m^s}$$

It can be empirically observed that, for $s > 2$, then,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big[\zeta(s)-H_n(s)\Big] = \zeta(s-1)-\zeta(s)$$

Can anyone prove this is true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\zeta(s) - H_n(s)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^s}$$ $$= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{k-1}{k^s} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} k^{1-s} - \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} k^{-s} $$$$=\zeta(s-1) - 1 - (\zeta(s) - 1) =  \zeta(s-1) - \zeta(s)$$

since each term $\frac{1}{k^s}$ appears in exactly $k-1$ of the sums $\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^2}$ (namely, for $n=1,..,k-1$).

Comment: And the interchange  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=n+1}^\infty = \sum_{m=2}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^{m-1}$ is justified by absolute convergence for $\text{Re}(s-1) > 1$.

Comment: Thanks, Cocopuffs. It is good to know it is true.

Answer (score 4):

$$\zeta(s) - H_n(s) = \sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{m^s}$$
Hence, $$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\zeta(s) - H_n(s)) & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{m^s}\\& = \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \dfrac1{m^s} \text{ (Changing the order of summation)}\\& = \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \left( \dfrac1{m^{s-1}} - \dfrac1{m^s}\right)\\
& = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left( \dfrac1{m^{s-1}} - \dfrac1{m^s}\right)\\
& = \zeta(s-1) - \zeta(s)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks, Marvis. It seems MS does not allow 2 answers to be accepted, so I chose the first one. Yours is elegant too.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII No worries. Both of us answered roughly at the same time and Cocopuffs answer has an earlier time stamp. So it is perfectly fine accepting his answer.